# How to set JetBrains IDEs darcula color scheme theme on Vim?

Tags: vim

Due to migration from JetBrains `WebStorm` IDE to `Vim`, I set an awesome environment configuration on `Vim` but for some reason, I wanna set **Darcula** color scheme theme on Vim.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, after search on and on over three days, I found a little and simple solution, if you wanna have JetBrains **Darcula** color scheme theme on your **Vim** please attention to these steps:

1. `cd .vim`
2. `mkdir colors`
3. `cd colors`
4. `touch darcula.vim`
5. copy below codes into `darcula.vim` file, (*also you can use [this file](https://github.com/blueshirts/darcula/blob/master/colors/darcula.vim)*)

   ```
   "
   " Darcula colorscheme for VIM.
   "

   highlight clear

   if exists("syntax_on")
     syntax reset
   endif

   let g:colors_name = "darcula"

   hi Cursor ctermfg=188 ctermbg=250 cterm=NONE guifg=#2b2b2b guibg=#a9b7c6 gui=NONE
   hi Visual ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=24 cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=#214283 gui=NONE
   hi CursorLine ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=236 cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=#323232 gui=NONE
   hi CursorColumn ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=236 cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=#313335 gui=NONE
   hi ColorColumn ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=236 cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=#313335 gui=NONE
   hi CursorLineNr ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=24 cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=#214283 gui=NONE
   hi VertSplit ctermfg=60 ctermbg=236 cterm=NONE guifg=#555555 guibg=#323232 gui=NONE
   hi MatchParen ctermfg=173 ctermbg=NONE cterm=underline guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=underline
   hi StatusLine ctermfg=67 ctermbg=236 cterm=bold guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#323232 gui=bold
   hi StatusLineNC ctermfg=188 ctermbg=236 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#323232 gui=NONE
   hi Search term=reverse ctermfg=188 ctermbg=24 guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#214283 gui=none
   hi IncSearch term=reverse ctermfg=188 ctermbg=24 guifg=#323232 guibg=#b1c73d gui=none
   hi Directory ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#9676ac guibg=NONE gui=italic
   hi Folded ctermfg=244 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE guifg=#8e9292 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE

   hi Normal ctermfg=188 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE
   hi Boolean ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi Character ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#9676ac guibg=NONE gui=italic
   hi Comment ctermfg=244 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#8e9292 guibg=NONE gui=none
   hi Conditional ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi Constant ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#9676ac guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi Define ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi DiffAdd ctermfg=188 ctermbg=64 cterm=bold guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#365546 gui=bold
   hi DiffDelete ctermfg=88 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#8c0909 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi DiffChange ctermfg=188 ctermbg=23 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#263b59 gui=NONE
   hi DiffText ctermfg=188 ctermbg=24 cterm=bold guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#204a87 gui=bold
   hi ErrorMsg ctermfg=15 ctermbg=88 cterm=NONE guifg=#ffffff guibg=#990000 gui=NONE
   hi WarningMsg ctermfg=15 ctermbg=88 cterm=NONE guifg=#ffffff guibg=#990000 gui=NONE
   hi Float ctermfg=67 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#7ca8c6 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi Function ctermfg=221 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi Identifier ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi Keyword ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi Label ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#9676ac guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi NonText ctermfg=188 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE guifg=#888888 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE
   hi Number ctermfg=67 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#7ca8c6 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi Operator ctermfg=250 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi PreProc ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi Special ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi SpecialKey ctermfg=250 ctermbg=236 cterm=NONE guifg=#bfbfbf guibg=#313335 gui=NONE
   hi Statement ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi StorageClass ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold

   hi String ctermfg=65 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#5e8759 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi Tag ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi Title ctermfg=159 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi Todo ctermfg=148 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#b1c73d guibg=NONE gui=bold,italic
   hi Type ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi Underlined ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=underline guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=underline
   hi htmlTag ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d9c767 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi htmlEndTag ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d9c767 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi htmlTagName ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d9c767 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi htmlString ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#8dc35b guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi htmlArg ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi htmlSpecialChar ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#67609c guibg=NONE gui=italic
   hi yamlKey ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi yamlAnchor ctermfg=67 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#7ca8c6 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi yamlAlias ctermfg=67 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#7ca8c6 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi yamlDocumentHeader ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=#292929 gui=NONE
   hi cssURL ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi cssFunctionName ctermfg=59 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#3c4c72 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi cssColor ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#9676ac guibg=NONE gui=italic
   hi cssPseudoClassId ctermfg=188 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d0d0ff guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi cssClassName ctermfg=188 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d0d0ff guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi cssValueLength ctermfg=67 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#7ca8c6 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi cssCommonAttr ctermfg=28 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#06960e guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi cssBraces ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=NONE

   " Adjust the gutter.
   let g:gitgutter_override_sign_column_highlight = 0 " Tell git gutter to leave the background alone.
   hi SignColumn ctermfg=60 ctermbg=236 cterm=NONE guifg=#888888 guibg=#323232 gui=NONE
   hi LineNr ctermfg=60 ctermbg=236 cterm=NONE guifg=#888888 guibg=#323232 gui=NONE

   " Extra Ruby highlighting.
   hi rubyClass ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyFunction ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyInterpolationDelimiter ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi rubySymbol ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#67609c guibg=NONE gui=italic
   hi rubyConstant ctermfg=68 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#9676ac guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyStringDelimiter ctermfg=65 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#5e8759 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi rubyBlockParameter ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi rubyInstanceVariable ctermfg=66 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#318495 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi rubyInclude ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyGlobalVariable ctermfg=66 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#318495 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi rubyRegexp ctermfg=65 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#5e8759 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi rubyRegexpDelimiter ctermfg=65 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#5e8759 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi rubyEscape ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyControl ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyClassVariable ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi rubyOperator ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyException ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyPseudoVariable ctermfg=66 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#318495 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi rubyRailsUserClass ctermfg=256 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#bbbbbb guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyRailsARAssociationMethod ctermfg=59 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#3c4c72 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyRailsARMethod ctermfg=59 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#3c4c72 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyRailsRenderMethod ctermfg=59 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#3c4c72 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi rubyRailsMethod ctermfg=59 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#3c4c72 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi erubyDelimiter ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi erubyComment ctermfg=244 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#8e9292 guibg=NONE gui=italic
   hi erubyRailsMethod ctermfg=59 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#3c4c72 guibg=NONE gui=bold

   " Extra js highlighting.
   hi jsFuncName ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d9c767 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi jsFunction ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   "hi jsNoise ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi jsFuncCall ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d9c767 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi jsComment ctermfg=244 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#8e9292 guibg=NONE gui=none
   hi jsBlockComment ctermfg=65 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#5e8759 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi jsDocTags ctermfg=65 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#5e8759 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi jsDocType ctermfg=65 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#5e8759 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi jsFunctionKey ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi jsCommonJs ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   "hi jsParen ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi jsParen ctermfg=188 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE
   "hi jsFuncBlock ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#67609c guibg=NONE gui=italic
   hi javaScriptFunction ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi javaScriptRailsFunction ctermfg=59 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#3c4c72 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi javaScriptBraces ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi jsObjectKey ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#9676ac guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi jsGlobalObjects ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=#9676ac guibg=NONE gui=bold


   " Extra Markdown highlighing.
   hi markdownHeadingDelimiter ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold
   hi markdownH1 ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi markdownH2 ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi markdownH3 ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi markdownH4 ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi markdownH5 ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi markdownH6 ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=NONE

   " Extra Jade highlighing.
   hi jadeId ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#67609c guibg=NONE gui=italic
   hi jadeClass ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#9676ac guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi jadePipedText ctermfg=65 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#5e8759 guibg=NONE gui=NONE

   " Extra JSON highlighting.
   hi jsonBraces ctermfg=188 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE

   " Extra CoffeeScript highlighting.
   hi coffeeObject ctermfg=188 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE
   hi coffeeObjAssign ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d9c767 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi coffeeSpecialVar ctermfg=188 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE

   " Extra Java highlighting.
   hi javaAnnotation ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d9c767 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi javaTypeDef ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d9c767 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   "hi javaOperator ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d9c767 guibg=NONE gui=NONE

   " Extra VIM highlighting.
   hi vimOption ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d9c767 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi vimUserFunc ctermfg=222 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#d9c767 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi vimCommand ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi vimParenSep ctermfg=188 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE
   hi vimVar ctermfg=188 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE
   hi vimFuncName ctermfg=103 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=NONE gui=NONE
   hi vimIsCommand ctermfg=188 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE

   " Extra CtrlP highlighting.
   hi CtrlPMatch term=reverse ctermfg=188 ctermbg=24 guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#214283 gui=none

   " Python specific highlighting.
   hi pythonOperator ctermfg=172 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#c57825 guibg=NONE gui=bold

   " Popup Highlighing.
   hi Pmenu ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=238 cterm=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=#323232 gui=NONE
   hi PmenuSel ctermfg=188 ctermbg=24 term=reverse guifg=NONE guibg=#214283 gui=NONE
   hi PmenuSbar  ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=24 guifg=NONE guibg=#8e9292
   hi PmenuThumb ctermfg=59 ctermbg=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE

   " Spelling highlighting.
   hi clear SpellBad
   hi clear SpellCap
   hi clear SpellRare
   hi clear SpellLocal
   hi SpellBad ctermfg=150 ctermbg=NONE cterm=undercurl term=undercurl guifg=#aeae80 guibg=NONE gui=undercurl
   hi SpellCap ctermfg=150 ctermbg=NONE cterm=undercurl guifg=#aeae80 guibg=NONE gui=undercurl
   hi SpellRare ctermfg=150 ctermbg=NONE cterm=undercurl guifg=#aeae80 guibg=NONE gui=undercurl
   hi SpellLocal ctermfg=150 ctermbg=NONE cterm=undercurl guifg=#aeae80 guibg=NONE gui=undercurl

   " NonText are 'end of the window' symbols, showbreak and various others. See :he highlight-groups
   hi NonText ctermfg=244 ctermbg=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#8e9292 guibg=NONE gui=none

   " Highlighting for built-in tabs.
   hi TabLineFill ctermfg=146 ctermbg=16 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE
   hi TabLine ctermfg=146 ctermbg=16 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#2b2b2b gui=NONE
   hi TabLineSel ctermfg=146 ctermbg=59 cterm=NONE guifg=#a9b7c6 guibg=#515658 gui=NONE

   set background=dark
   ```
6. `cd ~`
7. edit the `.vimrc` file or if you don't have it make it by using `touch` command and add the following command into the first lines of the `.vimrc` file:

   ```
   syntax enable
   colorscheme darcula
   ```
8. close the `Vim` and re-open it and **ENJOY**.